# insert and select using knex like the sql ex

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to generate a query like an example SQL query  :

```
    INSERT into [school_tasks_daily] (school_id, task_id) 
     SELECT 7, task_id 
     FROM homework_tasks
     WHERE day = sunday
```

I want to insert values into the table homework_tasks and create several columns with the id that I already created in the table school_tasks_daily .
because there are several homework tasks, that belong on the same day.

I tried the following in knex

```
  knex('school]').insert(function() {
  this.select('school_id', task_id)
    .from('school_tasks_daily')
    .whereNotExists(function() {
      this.select([ 7,  task_id ])
        .from('homework_tasks')
        .where('day', sunday))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like knex currently supports inserting from a select clause where you can explicitly choose the columns.

I think the best you can do for now is specify the insert part via `.raw` and keep the select as a query builder, i.e.

```js
knex.from(knex.raw('?? (??, ??)', ['school_tasks_daily', 'school_id', 'task_id']))
.insert(function () {
    this.select([7, 'task_id'])
    .from('homework_tasks')
    .where('day', 'sunday')
});
```